# button background changes to default after exiting the app

Tags: android, button, background, material-design

In my app there are three buttons for which the default background is set in xml file as android:setBackground("@drawable...") and this background changes after click on button but, whenever we restart app, buttons background get default i.e(from xml) i want to change the background after resume the app(as on click it was)  in short how to save the changed background of the button on resume.

Comment: Use SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store button click count in `SharedPreference`

like

```
prefs.edit().putInt("button1Cnt", 1%numOfBackgourndColors).commit()
```

Then you can get that int value in `onResume()` and set background to button as below

```
switch(prefs.getInt("button1Cnt",0))
{
     case 0:
         // set default color
          break;
     case 1:
         // another color
          break;
     case default:

}
```

Comment: @prashantB Do accept :) that is way to say thanks on SO.

Comment: Well, I have done that but as my reputation is below 15 I can't do that. I will sure do that

Comment: :) haha,,, yup buddy